# Proper use of onChangeText in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am fairly new to React Native and I have problem with using onChangeText.
I am trying to have a TextInput to type in a word and updating a state. When I use onChangeText I can only type 1 symbol at a time until it re-renders. I can keep the value by using
`value = {this.state.text}` but the input field still lose focus everytime I write a letter.

I have also tried using onBlur and onSubmitEditing with no success.

This is my current code. Which is inside render().

```
 <View style={{padding: 10}}>
   <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({text: text})} }
    />
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}>
         <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
            <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
      {this.state.text}
    </Text>
  </View>
```

So by using this method I can currently only write one letter at a time as this.state.text will only consist of one letter at a time.

Any help appreciated.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whwFx.gif)

**SOLVED**

I used react-native-tab-view which uses it's own router.
I wrote my code as [this](https://snack.expo.io/@croome/intrigued-watermelon)
And as you see the rendering part happens outside of return(). That's what caused my problem.
I've removed react-native-tab-view and rewritten it like [this](https://snack.expo.io/@croome/cmFudG)

Comment: I don't mean to be a stickler but you shouldn't be binding like that, it's technically fine but this will cause performance problems in larger apps. Bind in the constructor instead, or declare methods that need to be bound as `method = (args) =>` to avoid having to bind alltogether

Comment: I remade this in a snack: https://snack.expo.io/Hk-3w9x3m and it works fine, no issues with the text input blurring, so the problem is definitely elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this full component hope so this helpfull for u.

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text:''
        };
    }

    render() {
        let {text}=this.state;

        return ( 
            <View style={{padding: 10}}>
                <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ text: text})}}/>
                    <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
                    {text}
                    </Text>
            </View>
        )
     }
  }

  export default Home;
```

Comment: This one works. The problem is probably that my <View> is outside return() ?

Comment: Wait what? how is outside return ?

Comment: I am using react-native-tab-view, I think that's how

Comment: Hmm, don't really get it, but anyway, don't use `{this.state.variable}` , will always trigger a rerender. That was your issue here.

Comment: @oma `{this.state.variable}` this is not an issue if update ur state or props so  rerender ur component.

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextInput style={styles.input}
     placeholder='username'
     onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ username: text})}}>
</TextInput>
```

You need `{` `}` to open and close the function block, else it return the `setState`

`() => callFn` is equivalent with `() => {return callFn}` so you return your setState call.
You need here `() => {callFn}`

And remove the `{this.state.text}` from your `<Text>` tag, that will trigger rerender every time you change the `state`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was just a typo on my end. I was editing the code. Same issue occurs

Comment: Hmm okay, can you look at example picture and maybe know what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you try to remove the `TouchableHighlight` for a test?

Comment: But i got your issue.. it is because your `<Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
      {this.state.text}
    </Text>` this usage of your state is the issue, remove this and will work

Comment: You use the `this.state.text ` in your DOM, so new DOM will not be equal with the old(virtual) DOM, that's why will rerender.

Comment: I have tried removing that, just tried it again. Same issue occurs. My code now looks like  <View>
       <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({text: text})} }
        />
      </View> and issue still occurs

Comment: Maybe you use somewhere else the `this.state.someVariable` in the DOM..

Answer (score 0):

It is not best practice to create functions within component props.  This will always force a re-render even if nothing was changed due to the fact that the prop value is a new function.
Try it like this.
I also gave you a way to have multiple text inputs without creating a single inline function by use of "currying", along with making them into controlled inputs whereby their value is "controlled" by the state.  Socialism in React!

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name:''
      email:''
      nameError:''
      emailError:''
    };
  }

  onChangeText = name => text => this.setState({ [name]: text });

  render() {
    let { name, email, nameError, emailError } = this.state;

    return ( 
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput onChangeText={this._onChangeText("name")} value={name} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{nameError}</Text>
        <TextInput onChangeText={this._onChangeText("email"} value={email} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{emailError}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 42
  },
  container: {
    padding: 10
  }
});

export default Home;
```